# Wordpress Gallery Name Structure

Tags: wordpress, naming, gallery

This website [annapogossova.com](http://www.annapogossova.com) is set up through wordpress.

As you can see each "gallery" is set up as a page, with an iFrame linking to the actual html gallery.

The problem is - Anna would like to call each item in the drop down menu - Gallery 1, Gallery 2, Gallery 3 etc..

This would be horrendous to manage as each page would then be called Gallery 1, Gallery 2, Gallery 3 etc..

What's the best way around this situation?

I'm running wordpress 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never Mind -

Wordpress 3 allows for "Menus". You can actually specify the Navigation Label in the admin>Menus section.

All fixed. 
Thanks